# grep - separation after different file

Tags: grep, console, text-formatting

I'm using `grep` to look for a specific string in log-files. It's sometimes a little tricky to see the output refers to the next file already, like:

```
354058:c1.com/client-01.log:13:30:04 INFO:       Item: created widget in ARRIVALS
360746:c1.com/client-01.log:13:39:46 INFO:          change transfer to contact
379144:c3.com/client-01.log:13:30:02 INFO:       Item: created widget in ARR
392162:c3.com/client-01.log:13:51:59 INFO:       Item: created widget in ARR
367422:c5.com/client-01.log:13:51:56 INFO:       searching for Sign 
367446:c5.com/client-01.log:13:51:59 INFO:       Item: created widget in ARRIVALS
367629:c5.com/client-01.log:13:52:12 INFO:          change from initial to contact
371979:c9.com/client-01.log:14:00:19 INFO:          change workflow to tgl
```

Is there a way to put a separator after each file?

Comment: There's nothing like that built into `grep`. Use a `for` loop to grep+print separator for each file or, if you know that your file names _can not_ contain colons, post-process the output to insert a separator before each new filename e.g. `grep [...] | awk -F':' '!seen[$1]++{printf "%s\n", "DELIMITER"};1'`

Comment: You can try grep -0, It's not perfect but you get separator

Comment: @ctac_ - it separates after each line, that's just making things even more confusing